# Word Count Number is always changing, when using Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to create word count example with flink. Here is the [link](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/wordcount/util/WordCountData.java) for words data (this is the example from flink's github account)

When I count the words with simple java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int count = 0;
    for (String eachSentence : WordCountData.WORDS){
        String[] splittedSentence = eachSentence.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
        for (String eachWord: splittedSentence){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
// result is 287
}
```

Now when I do this with flink, first I will split the sentence to words.

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> readWordByWordStream = splitSentenceWordByWord(wordCountDataSource);

//...
public DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> splitSentenceWordByWord(DataStream<String> wordDataSourceStream)
{
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordByWordStream = wordDataSourceStream.flatMap(new TempTransformation());
    return wordByWordStream;
 }
```

- Here is the my `TempTransformation`class:

```java
public class TempTransformation extends RichFlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    @Override
    public void flatMap(String input, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> collector) throws Exception
    {
        String[] splittedSentence = input.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
        for (String eachWord : splittedSentence)
        {
            collector.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(eachWord, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

- Now I am going to count the words by converting it to KeyedStream (keyed by word)

```java
    public SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> keyedStreamExample(DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordByWordStream)
    {
        return wordByWordStream.keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.milliseconds(1)).apply(new TempWindowFunction());
    }
```

- TempWindowFunction():

```java
public class TempWindowFunction extends RichWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String, Tuple, TimeWindow> {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TempWindowFunction.class);
    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void apply(Tuple tuple, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> input, Collector<String> out) throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("Key is:' {} ' and collected element for that key and count: {}", (Object) tuple.getField(0), count);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Tuple2 each : input)
        {
            String key = (String) each.getField(0);
            Integer value = (Integer) each.getField(1);
            String tupleStr = "[ " + key + " , " + value + "]";
            builder.append(tupleStr);
            count ++;
        }
        logger.info("All tuples {}", builder.toString());
        logger.info("Exit method");
        logger.info("----");
    }
}
```

- After running this job with Flink's local environments, outputs always changing, here is the a few samples:

```
18:09:40,086 INFO  com.sampleFlinkProject.transformations.TempWindowFunction     - Key is:' rub ' and collected element for that key and count: 86
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - All tuples [ rub , 1]
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Exit method
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - ----
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Key is:' for ' and collected element for that key and count: 87
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - All tuples [ for , 1]
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Exit method
18:09:40,086 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - ----

// another running outputs:

18:36:21,660 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Key is:' for ' and collected element for that key and count: 103
18:36:21,660 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - All tuples [ for , 1]
18:36:21,660 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Exit method
18:36:21,660 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - ----
18:36:21,662 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Key is:' coil ' and collected element for that key and count: 104
18:36:21,662 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - All tuples [ coil , 1]
18:36:21,662 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - Exit method
18:36:21,662 INFO  TempWindowFunction     - ----
```

- Lastly, here is the execution setup

```java
//...
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(1);
//...
```

- Why Flink is giving different outputs for each execution?

Answer (score 1):

One source of non-determinism in your application is the processing time windows (which are 1 ms long). Whenever you use processing time for windowing, then the windows end up containing whatever events happen to show up and get processed during the time interval. (Event time windows do behave deterministically, since they are based on timestamps in the events.) Having the windows be so short is going to exaggerate this effect.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize this. Is there any document that visualize this situation?

Comment: https://training.ververica.com/lessons/event-time-watermarks.html is a good starting point.